# make Qt application fails on fedora 20 : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile

I am following this [example](http://csl.name/qt-gcc/) here.
This is the output I get for make

```
admin@localhost qtest$ make
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -o qtest qtest.o   -L/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qtest] Error 1
admin@localhost qtest$
```

My cpp file is this

```
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 30 );
    hello.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

**Update**

This is what I  get after

```
 sudo yum install mesa-libGL-devel -y
```

Trying again to build :

```
admin@localhost qtest$ make
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -o qtest qtest.o   -L/home/admin/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
qtest.o: In function `main':
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x22): undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4f): undefined reference to `QPushButton::QPushButton(QString const&, QWidget*)'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x74): undefined reference to `QWidget::resize(QSize const&)'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7c): undefined reference to `QWidget::show()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x81): undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8c): undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0x94): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0xab): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbe): undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
qtest.cpp:(.text.startup+0xce): undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qtest] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up your foo.pro file.

You probably have something like:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Mon Nov 17 14:00:29 2014
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += foo.cpp
```

Add to the top, "QT += widgets", such that your file now reads:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Mon Nov 17 14:00:29 2014
######################################################################

QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += foo.cpp
```

then run `qmake` and `make`. This should allow it to find the relevant headers.

Your second error is not with libraries, but with finding the QtCore and QtWidgets modules of Qt.

Answer (score 4):

To solve your error :

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

you should install the missing mesa package by running the following install command as root or using `sudo` :

```
sudo yum install mesa-libGL-devel -y
```